# Formal way to prove discontinuity of function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, piecewise-continuity

Say I want to show the function f(x)=x+1 when x is rational and f(x)=2x when x is irrational is only continuous at 1.

Clearly, it is only continuous when x=1. To show this, I proved $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = f(1) $ by considering the limit of both pieces. I'm not sure if this is correct though. Is there a way to do this by definition?

I'm also a little stuck how to show f(x) is discontinuous elsewhere rigorously, though. Would I do it by delta-epsilon definition of continuity? By finding a sequence (x_n)->c where f(x_n)-/->f(c)?

Comment: Why not show how you proved it in details? This way we can better check your approach. The sequence argument may be a good way as it seems you are familiar with it.

Comment: To prove continuity, I would use either $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ or squeeze theorem, using the two lines as upper/lower bounds. If I were using the latter, I would probably also consider the left and right limits separately, since the dominant line changes on each side. To prove discontinuity, I would stick to the sequential argument. An $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ argument is possible, but using the definition to disprove a limit directly can be tricky if you haven't seen it before.

Comment: To show discontinuity, I said define a sequence (r_n)->x of rationals and (i_n)->x of irrationals. I then said that f(r_n) = r_n + 1 -> x + 1 but then f(i_n) = 2 i_n -> 2x. And x+1 equals 2x only when x=1, so f is discontinuous at all other points. Is this correct?

Comment: @user124820929 That correctly shows that all the points other than $x = 1$ are discontinuities (which is an important step). It doesn't show that the function is continuous at $x = 1$ (finding a rational and irrational sequence that confirm the limit is not enough, as you may have just been lucky in which sequences you picked). To prove the limit, you'll need to do an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ argument at the $x = 1$ point.